# Need correct regular expression for Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I am creating `regular expression in Jmeter` for following response:

```
/cars/contractDispatcher.do?
operation=programHeader&amp;id=265&amp;hierarchyName=ContractAsHierarchy
```

id=265 is dynamic in this expression, I am tried with following expression:

```
/cars/contractDispatcher.do?operation=programHeader&id="
(.+?)"&hierarchyName=ContractAsHierarchy
```

Also:

```
operation=programHeader&id=([^>]+)&hierarchyName=ContractAsHierarchy
```

**Question**

But these are not working could anyone tell me correct expression.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Reference Name: any variable name, i.e. `id`
- Regular Expression (single line): `operation=programHeader&amp;id=(\d+)&amp;hierarchyName=ContractAsHierarchy`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer extracted value as `${id}` where required.

You can use RegExp Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to evaluate regular expressions directly against response

[image: RegExp Tester]

For more information on:

- Regular Expressions - see [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter's User Manual
- Debugging JMeter Test - check out [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide

Comment: Hello & Thanks for ans.
I tried with your logic as well but it seems it is not working for me.
In my Regular expression Extractor is as below
RefName:ID
Expression:operation=programHeader&amp;id=(\d+)&amp;hierarchyName=ContractAsHierarchy
Template:$1$
Match :1
I have built my expression as above but still it is not showing me id.
For more clearity i have pasted below code from response of the request. 
href="javascript:hmDispatchUrl('/cars/contractDispatcher.do?operation=priceGroupPricing&amp;id=266&amp;hierarchyName=ContractAsHierarchy','PriceGroupPricing:266','true',null, null, null,'1');">

Comment: Maybe it comes in the sub-sample, need to see screenshot of your test plan with response in the view results tree listener preferably in RegExp Tester mode